# Is this a Dirac comb?

Tags: dirac-delta, piecewise-continuity

While playing around, I came across the following function

$$f(x)=\lceil\{|x|\}\rceil$$

Its $0$ at integers, $1$ otherwise.(The mod is to extend it to $x<0$)

So I made
$$g(x)=\frac1{f(x)}-1$$

which blows up for ints and $0$ otherwise. It looks like a Dirac comb but I have a feeling it isn't. Is $g$ a Dirac Comb?

Comment: No. $\delta$ is a distribution, not a function. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$